# What is "Untracked" and "Modified" in Vs Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm learning react and whenever I create a new component every component I create is marked as `UNTRACKED`, but the files which are auto generated by "npx create-react-app" are marked as `MODIFIED` when I edit them.

But the question is what are these marks and do I have to care about them?

[image: The Files structure]

Comment: This has nothing to do with react, but instead with git, your version control system.

Answer (score 1):

**Modified** - Files that have been edited since your last commit.

**Untracked** - Any files in your working directory that were not in your last snapshot and are not in your staging area.

This warnings are git warnings,
you can get rid of them by committing your changes

```
git add .
git commit -m "Any message - what you have done since your last commit"
```